# hierarchyviewer tool is missing

Tags: android

I'm looking for "[hierarchyviewer](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html)" tool, but it's missing in my SDK installation.
Is "[hierarchyviewer](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html)" part of Android SDK or there's something else I need to install on top of SDK to get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This appears to be a bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11214), at least on Windows. I'm not on my Linux box right now so I can't check that version at the moment.

Someone did post a link to the `hierarchyviewer.bat` source in the ticket's comments, though. You can access the source [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/sdk.git;a=blob_plain;f=hierarchyviewer/etc/hierarchyviewer.bat;hb=tools_r7).